# Angular 6 routing - Error _angular_router__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.RouterModule.forRootd is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

The version 6 of Angular CLI generates routing module differently, my app-routing.ts is as follows:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { TodoComponent } from './components/todo/todo.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' },
  { path: 'todo', component: TodoComponent }
];

export const AppRoutes = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

But my browser console points to the last line and shows the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError:
>   _angular_router__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.RouterModule.forRootd is not a function

[image]

After browsed the net and failed to find an answer [here too](https://angular.io/guide/router), I would ask, is it normal that CLI 6 doesn't generate any more route module that implement @ngModule with its imports and exports like it did in previous versions, example:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(crisisCenterRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
```

If not, what is the solution to this error ?

**Update:** and here is the code for my app-shared.module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutes } from './app.routing';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { TodoModule } from './components/todo/todo.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HeaderInterceptor } from './core/header.interceptor';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    TodoModule,
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutes
  ],
  providers: [
    {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: HeaderInterceptor,
        multi: true
    }
    ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppSharedModule { }
```

Comment: could you provide the code for **app-shared.module.ts**

Comment: @JohnVelasquez added the code for app-shared.module.ts

Comment: did you try doing hard reload in your browser?